# Architecting a department site with 2 TB+ of data

Tags: content-database, architecture

We are looking at the possibility of migrating 2TB+ worth of data from our network driving into SharePoint for a department site. For this question I'm assuming all data is valid and has the ability to be assigned to a custom content type and be given basic metadata.

If we did this, we would need to split the data between multiple site collections / content databases but ideally the user experience would be fairly seamless. Key functionality:
 - Users will be collaborating on about 5% of the content at any one time but we don’t currently have a way of determining what would be considered collaborative content and what would be classified as a record. Technically we do but I don’t believe the business is willing to do that on a document by document basis.

- Users can browse to their content
- Users can search for their content
- As more content is added we will need to add additional content databases. Existing content may need to be moved to those content databases but the experience should stay constant. I.e., I’m trying to avoid the scenario of documents used to be in SiteA/DocLib1 but now you have to go to SiteB/DocLib1.

**Question**

What concepts / whitepapers should be researched in order to evaluate this?

Comment: What version of SP and SQL server are you running, that might be beneficial.

Comment: SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a large database, you should create site collection with separate content db. You can't do this through UI, so you have to create the structure programmatically.

You can refer following whitepaper:
[Managing Multi-Terabyte Content Databases with SharePoint 2010 (white paper)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/hh307867%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the information, it told me what I need to know which is unfortunately managing multi TBs is not really what SP does best. We've decided to push these requests into our Documentum system and referece that data through custom webparts in SP.